# Unable to get all data joined using merge(..., all=TRUE)?

Tags: r, date, join, merge, na

I have two data frames which have time series data.

I want to merge both data on times. I used the following command:

```
m=merge(mydata7,mydata1,by="times",all =TRUE)
```

Now as you can see it is missing time 07:02 from `mydate1` i am not getting why it is missing this.. i want to have both data and missing fields is replaced by previous value not by `NA`

Here's the data:

```
mydata1 =
structure(list(times = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L),
.Label = c("4/1/2016 11:02", 
"4/1/2016 7:02", "4/1/2016 7:12", "4/1/2016 7:22", "4/1/2016 7:32", 
"4/1/2016 7:42", "4/1/2016 7:52", "4/1/2016 8:02", "4/1/2016 8:12", 
"4/1/2016 8:22", "4/1/2016 8:32", "4/1/2016 8:42", "4/1/2016 8:52", 
"4/1/2016 9:02", "4/1/2016 9:12", "4/1/2016 9:22", "4/1/2016 9:32", 
"4/1/2016 9:42", "4/1/2016 9:52", "4/4/2016 3:40", "4/4/2016 3:50", 
"4/4/2016 4:00", "4/4/2016 4:10", "4/4/2016 4:20", "4/4/2016 4:30", 
"4/4/2016 4:40", "4/4/2016 4:50", "4/4/2016 5:00", "4/4/2016 5:10", 
"4/4/2016 5:20", "4/4/2016 5:30", "4/4/2016 5:40", "4/4/2016 5:50", 
"4/4/2016 6:00", "4/4/2016 6:10", "4/4/2016 6:20", "4/4/2016 6:30", 
"4/4/2016 6:40", "4/4/2016 6:50", "4/4/2016 7:00", "4/4/2016 7:10", 
"4/4/2016 7:20"), class = "factor"),
Open = c(16.72278698, 15.97135403, 
16.2502484, 16.86737499, 17.38982271, 17.06200904, 16.35144742, 
16.6608737, 17.40656438, 18.19878622, 18.4953396, 17.44738486, 
18.03041568, 17.86379046, 17.37890132, 17.8113319, 18.37371163, 
17.5946693, 17.88193098, 15.26577796, 17.787945, 17.56781029, 
16.61562991, 17.20046034, 17.92410221, 17.90279521, 16.68541461, 
15.6198332, 15.66647794, 15.61947799, 15.91357169, 16.16975574, 
16.10266875, 16.48827516, 16.26887133, 16.00361772, 15.70874174, 
16.33110122, 14.98407633, 14.83423362, 15.43892116, 14.06661966),
High = c(16.61218206, 16.30941276, 16.46179687, 17.73242121, 
17.40803494, 16.69500997, 17.12121055, 17.24161281, 18.02573482, 
18.25816418, 17.89118875, 17.39486004, 18.58667227, 17.75906328, 
18.30440156, 18.18327367, 18.22871169, 17.99796892, 18.28241531, 
17.31179538, 17.50683646, 17.13081502, 17.50058581, 18.17055388, 
17.37001367, 17.70375921, 16.12400885, 17.02340347, 15.91559658, 
16.45389754, 16.048561, 16.51394532, 15.91181307, 15.8907224, 
15.32549299, 16.27648947, 16.27259065, 16.02847019, 15.0412349, 
15.03729263, 14.70711405, 15.76516567),
Low = c(15.82402235, 
15.37087088, 15.75891471, 16.29799388, 16.40233601, 16.21816259, 
16.86277766, 16.46255269, 16.99852627, 17.71896219, 17.77013371, 
16.61218982, 17.7642859, 17.87430506, 17.60668581, 17.78581347, 
16.91537413, 17.02232271, 17.79010116, 15.33341039, 17.26249235, 
17.33426018, 17.39939759, 17.38078114, 17.61103373, 15.63631299, 
16.14795684, 16.17203088, 15.05033241, 15.76103829, 16.40251489, 
16.23931193, 16.34181598, 16.23077018, 15.65055291, 15.80244449, 
16.31863567, 15.59777869, 15.09157678, 14.97958773, 14.67132113, 
15.00236144),
close = c(16.16988373, 16.45107987, 16.0544984, 
17.4521672, 17.1385357, 16.99446459, 16.85593712, 16.39238298, 
18.3873355, 17.43757583, 18.14751919, 17.17169022, 17.48942926, 
18.26623319, 17.72940093, 17.74653901, 17.39591443, 17.02606496, 
18.00364352, 18.07080708, 17.69129909, 16.68539826, 17.83899938, 
17.53001623, 17.07814804, 16.14477252, 15.67105975, 16.01777995, 
16.03061899, 15.77042054, 16.46061514, 16.08259587, 16.06298954, 
16.62616704, 15.44284088, 15.85393503, 16.04520034, 15.0713808, 
15.60909829, 15.39263265, 14.80231501, 15.43489693)),
.Names = c("times", "Open", "High", "Low", "close"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L))


mydata7 =
structure(list(times = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L), .Label = c("4/1/2016 11:01", 
"4/1/2016 7:01", "4/1/2016 7:11", "4/1/2016 7:21", "4/1/2016 7:31", 
"4/1/2016 7:41", "4/1/2016 8:21", "4/1/2016 8:31", "4/1/2016 8:41", 
"4/1/2016 8:51", "4/1/2016 9:01", "4/1/2016 9:11", "4/1/2016 9:21", 
"4/1/2016 9:31", "4/1/2016 9:41", "4/1/2016 9:51", "4/4/2016 3:45", 
"4/4/2016 3:55", "4/4/2016 4:05", "4/4/2016 4:25", "4/4/2016 4:35", 
"4/4/2016 4:45", "4/4/2016 5:05", "4/4/2016 5:15", "4/4/2016 6:05", 
"4/4/2016 6:45", "4/4/2016 7:05", "4/4/2016 7:15", "4/4/2016 7:25", 
"4/4/2016 7:35", "4/4/2016 7:45", "4/4/2016 7:55", "4/4/2016 8:15", 
"4/4/2016 8:25", "4/4/2016 8:45", "4/4/2016 8:55", "4/4/2016 9:15", 
"4/4/2016 9:25", "4/4/2016 9:35", "4/4/2016 9:45", "4/4/2016 9:55"
), class = "factor"), Open = c(451.1886228, 449.4212867, 451.4615165, 
451.1482766, 452.3053128, 451.5482317, 454.4575053, 453.9436549, 
453.1828612, 454.4282375, 454.6100063, 453.6519749, 454.0431538, 
452.8947017, 453.4831806, 452.8326541, 455.8985985, 452.2680598, 
453.2629865, 453.4039409, 453.2160163, 452.4927456, 451.8070642, 
449.3808479, 450.6853928, 449.3944732, 447.7458839, 447.6836593, 
448.3455733, 447.9036679, 447.1341682, 447.5492552, 447.7067299, 
448.2253611, 449.2601729, 448.0682437, 448.8729166, 449.2426588, 
450.5222366, 449.4723271, 450.0636792), High = c(450.8124209, 
449.272124, 450.9626045, 451.2204223, 451.9714763, 454.4935027, 
455.5178115, 453.2423269, 453.194444, 454.5951709, 454.1375549, 
453.4393663, 453.9353145, 453.6523212, 452.6024881, 452.9658457, 
455.3084733, 453.2023004, 453.704359, 453.2921532, 453.5388983, 
452.0837367, 451.1964962, 451.7064709, 450.3598393, 449.3812282, 
448.0563508, 448.6560677, 449.8208711, 447.3066134, 447.783045, 
447.6497169, 448.0156386, 448.2689689, 449.1497844, 449.0279737, 
448.5201206, 449.7131206, 449.6174205, 450.2479593, 450.6973705
), Low = c(449.2689228, 449.8494337, 451.4297673, 450.3847865, 
450.8154675, 451.4656641, 454.5929712, 453.8866844, 453.9363161, 
453.7459696, 454.1473172, 452.5797131, 454.4614194, 452.4159312, 
452.4458168, 453.2353506, 452.3642802, 452.3774042, 452.6485611, 
453.3248771, 453.6996322, 451.6874197, 449.8135407, 449.1804997, 
450.4841919, 448.0796094, 447.8684126, 447.7141988, 448.2171119, 
447.906635, 447.2796979, 448.0657512, 447.6734645, 448.3034072, 
449.4600224, 448.0461631, 448.6454065, 448.349104, 450.0543481, 
449.9894413, 449.8236391), close = c(449.2609004, 449.4053531, 
451.1122691, 451.7274693, 451.0326458, 454.3438439, 455.2809649, 
453.6682132, 453.9280758, 454.4603361, 454.204142, 452.6525043, 
453.7623646, 452.3093107, 452.8724432, 452.8153176, 452.3614086, 
453.0984373, 454.1264157, 452.7523412, 452.8282336, 451.0074535, 
450.4822089, 451.5704093, 450.2223655, 448.563143, 448.1693728, 
447.6999038, 448.0967266, 447.0993802, 448.1094835, 448.3651085, 
447.5408461, 447.5243577, 449.1473132, 448.5976211, 448.6235759, 
449.471077, 450.1042492, 450.3559352, 450.2732807)), .Names = c("times", 
"Open", "High", "Low", "close"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-41L))
```

Comment: is it further down in the data.frame?...you might want to save yourself some pain and avoid `merge` all together and focus on using join functions in dplyr: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#mutating-joins

Comment: @gjabel yes it has many rows..it is just the head part of data frame.. that means we can't have the desired result with merge?

Comment: you probably can... just the join functions are faster and easier to control. i could never fully get my head around the merge help file.

Comment: It looks like you need `rbind`, not `merge`, unless you have identical timestamps in each. You're not seeing both within `head` because there's no overlap; the rows from the other data.frame are further down and shifted into the new columns.

Comment: Please `dput()` your data to make it more easily reproducible. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: @Hack-R i didn't get your point do you want me to put all dput() data here in question?

Comment: @Grv Yes, please. In the R tag the official instructions are to share your data using `dput` (as opposed to `head()`, for instance) because `dput` allows us to reproduce your data directly, including data classes and metadata. If you hover your pointer over the `r` tag it shows the instructions for asking questions tagged with `r`.

Comment: @Hack-R I will update..was my first question in R..:|

Comment: Thanks. No worries.

Comment: the limit was 30k words so i used a small data ..hope it helps to understand what the issue is.Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126969/discussion-between-grv-and-hack-r).

Comment: Right, so that's why they require it to be a **Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable, Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It means if your real data is 10 billion rows but you can create a working example using only 5 rows of the 10 billion, then you share 5 rows not 10 billion. Your example should be complete but minimal. It should contain everything it needs to reflect the problem suitably, but nothing extra. If the data displayed in `head()` was enough then you shouldn't `dput()` more data than was in `head`. You can even `dput` the `head` itself, e.g. `dput(head(mydata))`.

Comment: so Head was my way to give minimal data..but now on i will try to give dput data of 6 rows..

Answer (score 3):

You didn't actually lose `4/1/2016 7:02` like you thought. It's actually still there on row 43 (using the example data in your question -- this may be a different row number in your real data).

The confusion seems to be from how the join (merge) works. You're joining on the `times` columns, and since there are no date/time values of `times` which are precisely the same in both datasets you have all records but the columns from the first dataset (`mydata7`) are always `NA` when values from the 2nd dataset (`mydata1`) exist and vice versa.

Thus when you say:

> i want to have both data and missing fields is replaced by previous
>   value not by NA

The part of your statement that says:

> i want to have both data

is already satisfied.

The part of your statement that says:

> missing fields is replaced by previous value not by NA

is unclear. You could define the "previous value" many different ways. For instance if you mean "previous" as in "last non-missing row" then the answer is:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(m)){
  for(j in 2:ncol(m)){
    if(is.na(m[i,j]) & !is.na(m[i-1,j])){
      m[i,j] <- m[i-1,j]
    }
  }
}
```

but this only eliminates `NA`s from one of the data sets and is probably not what you meant.

You probably meant the prior non-`NA` value based on date/time.

```
m$times <- lubridate::dmy_hm(m$times) # change factor to date/time

for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(m)){
    if(is.na(m[i,j])){
      if(length(m[m$times == min(m$times[!is.na(m[,j]) & m$times < m$times[i]]),j]) > 0){
      m[i,j] <- m[m$times == min(m$times[!is.na(m[,j]) & m$times < m$times[i]]),j]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That'll work for all except 1 row, wherein the timestamp was at its minimal value thus there were no prior values for filling in `NA` values.